# Show that sin(3x) = sin(x)(2cos(2x) + 1)

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently studying Trigonometric Functions and came to exercise where I am to find all possible values for x in the range of x[0, PI] where.

The equation is as follows:
sin(3x) = 0.39

I found two values possible for x but the solution in my exercise book shows 2 extra solutions.

Wolfram Alpha tells me that an alternate form of sin(3x) is sin(x)(2cos(2x)+1)

What I want to know is: how do I transform sin(3x) to be the alternate form, and how do I find all the possible solutions for x?

The measurements are in radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sin 3x &= \sin(x+2x)\\
&=\sin x\cos 2x + \sin 2x\cos x\\
&=\sin x\cos 2x +2\sin x\cos^2 x \\
&=\sin x(\cos 2x +2\cos^2x)\end{align}$$

But then remember $2\cos^2 x-1=\cos 2x$, so $2\cos^2 x=\cos 2x+1$

In general, when $n$ is an integer:

$$\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$$
can be written as a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $\cos x$. This polynomial is called a Chebyshev polynomial of the second type. It turns out, you can write it instead in terms of a linear combination of  $\cos(n-1)x,\cos(n-3)x,\dots$.

So $$\begin{align}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x} &= 2\cos x\\
\frac{\sin 3x}{\sin x} &= 2\cos 2x + 1\\
\frac{\sin 4x}{\sin x} &= 8\cos^3 x -4\cos x=2\cos 3x +2\cos x
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you - nicely structured.

I'm just wondering where 2cos^2(x) - 1 = cos(2x) comes from?

Comment: Put $a=b=x$ into $\cos (a+b)=\cos a \cos b -\sin a \sin b$ and $\sin^2 a=1-\cos^2 a$ and you get $ \cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use addition and duplication/linearisation formulae:
\begin{align*}
\sin(x+2x)&=\sin x\cos 2x+\cos x\sin2x=\sin x\cos 2x+\cos x\cdot2\sin x\cos x\\
&=\sin x(\cos x+2\cos^2x)=\sin x (\cos 2x+1+\cos 2x).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You can also think about the problem graphically: here's WolframAlpha's graph of $ y = .39$ and $y = \sin3x$. When you multiply $x$ by $3$, you compress the graph horizontally by a factor of 3. That's why you have the extra solutions.

[WolframAlpha graph y = .39 and y= sin 3x  http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP16611c24a18b46gb9i1500004fi0b0e9351f8ahd?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=61&w=368.&h=180.&cdf=RangeControl](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP16611c24a18b46gb9i1500004fi0b0e9351f8ahd?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=61&w=368.&h=180.&cdf=RangeControl)

Comment: Ah, thank you for addressing the extra solutions bit :)